# SharePoint 2013 JSOM User Key From Person Field

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

Can anyone help me to get the user info from a person column using javascript? So far I have been able to read the list item and return a SP.FieldUserValue from which I can get a numeric Id (not sure what this ID is) and the display name. e.g.

```
var ManVal  = oListItem.get_item("RecruitingManager").get_lookupValue();
var ManId   = oListItem.get_item("RecruitingManager").get_lookupId();
```

How do I take this one step further to create a sp user object?

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is to retrieve the details from the list and then populate a people editor.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've got it.

Here is my code, hope it helps somebody. I haven't included the method to retrieve the list item, just the line from that function where I'm getting the value of the person.

```
var _lineManager;

var lineManager = oListItem.get_item("RecruitingManager").get_lookupId();

_lineManager = oWebsite.getUserById(lineManager);

getLineManager();

function getLineManager() {
    context.load(_lineManager);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccessLM, onGetUserNameFailLM);
}
function onGetUserNameSuccessLM() {
    alert(lineManager.get_title());

    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

    var users = new Array(1);
    var defaultUser = new Object();
    defaultUser.AutoFillDisplayText = lineManager.get_title();
    defaultUser.AutoFillKey = lineManager.get_loginName();
    defaultUser.Description = lineManager.get_email();
    defaultUser.DisplayText = lineManager.get_title();
    defaultUser.EntityType = "User";
    defaultUser.IsResolved = true;
    defaultUser.Key = lineManager.get_loginName();
    defaultUser.Resolved = true;
    users[0] = defaultUser;

    SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper('peoplePickerDivLinMan', users, schema);

}

function onGetUserNameFailLM(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The person field (actually called "people picker") has a specific JavaScript function which you might find useful: `GetAllUserInfo()`

There is a nice article on MSDN:
[How to: Use the client-side People Picker control in apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713593%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

The relevant code is:

```
// Get the people picker object from the page.
var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

// Get information about all users.
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
var userInfo = '';
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    for (var userProperty in user) { 
        userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
    }
}
$('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);

// Get user keys.
var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
$('#userKeys').html(keys);
```

So basically you have to cast your field to a `SPClientPeoplePicker` and can then use `GetAllUserInfo` to iterate over all users in the field.

Comment: Thanks but I think you have misunderstood. I'm retrieving  the person value from a list item, not  people picker. I've read the article you have listed.

Comment: I did misunderstand, but your code especially get_lookupValue() should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892999/how-to-read-a-column-type-spuser-datetime-currency-with-ecmascript

Comment: Where I'm getting confused is, that look up value returns 
     SP.FieldUserValue - $1A_1: 11
     $2Z_1: "Phillip Hill"
     __proto__: Object
How do I get a user object from this so I can for instance get the email address of that user?
I can then use that to set the people picker.

All I'm trying to do is get a user from a person column in a list ad populate the people picker with this person. I'm obviously missing something obvious.